# is the product of totally ordered sets is total order

Tags: logic, order-theory, model-theory

I was working in products of structures and I am trying to find a counterexample to the following: "the product of totally ordered sets is a totally ordered set."  Unfortunately I could not find one. Can someone provide me with a counterexample?

Comment: How do you define product of ordered sets? I suppose $(A,\prec)\times(B,\sqsubset)$ will be $(A\times B,\text{something})$, but what is the something?

Comment: If your definition is $$(a,b)\mathrel{\rm something}(c,d) \iff a\prec c\, \land\, b\sqsubset d$$ then _every_ product where $A$ and $B$ both have at least $2$ element is a counterexample -- e.g. $(\{0,1\},<)^2$. On the other hand if "something" is a lexicographic order, then the claim is true, and there are no counterexamples at all.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to clarify that i mean the usual cartesian product of structures (I am studying model theory-lös theorem). So I meant the cartesian (infinite) product of totally ordered structures is a totall ordered structure

Comment: x @George: You should _explain which ordering you're using_ for $A\times B$ instead of just telling us the _name_ you're calling it by. Even if one looks up model-theoretic products, you still haven't revealed whether your total orders are based on a language with a strict or a non-strict order relation as primitive -- these two give _different partial orders_ when you take products.

Comment: What's the definition of the product of two structures? Not a rhetorical question - I had no idea there was such a thing. In particular, if $(A_1, R_1)$ and $(A_2,R_2)$ are two structures where $R_j$ is a binary relation on $A_j$, what's the definition of the product relation on $A_1\times A_2$?

Comment: Henning I just meant exactly what you wrote on your comment, That is how is defined the product of structures . I appreciate it

Comment: x @GeorgeChailos: Did you see the second part of my comment? **You need to tell us** what the vocabulary of the structures you're working with is, because the outcome of a product is different based on whether the relation in your language is supposed to be reflexive or strict.

Comment: Is a strict relation. Is irreflexive, transitive and total.

Comment: x @GeorgeChailos: Okay. (This kind of clarification should be edited into the question rather than hidden in a comment thread, but never mind). Are you still looking for a counterexample, then? Practically every pair of total orders you can come up with will be a counterexample -- as long as _at least_ one of the sets has more than one element.

Comment: If A and B are L-structures, we form their product C = A × B as follows. The elements of C are the ordered pairs (a,b) where a is an element of A and b is an element of B. The predicate symbols are interpreted ‘pointwise’, i.e. so that for example

(a,b) is in P_Cif and only if a is in P_Aand b is in P_B
The structures A and B are called the factors of A × B. In the same way we can form products of any number of structures. If all the factors of a product are the same structure A, the product is called a power of A.

Comment: @GeorgeChailos Great, thanks. Although then, as Henning said, it's hard to understand when you say you've looked for a counterexample but couldn't find one - the product of two total orders is not a total order except in trivial cases.

Comment: @GeorgeChailos What Henning said: You should edit the question to clarify the definition! My answer _is_ imo the right answer to the question that you actually asked, and as such it belongs here. Edit the question to what you meant to ask and my answer becomes irrelevant or wrong and goes away.

Comment: @GeorgeChailos The point being that when you refer to the product of two totally ordered sets without specifying you mean the model-theoretic definition, there really is no way the reader can know that's what you meant. Consider for example the product of two topological spaces. That has a standard definition, which is _not_ the model-theoretic definition. (Assuming in comments on topological spaces that we're doing set theory, so "topological space" is a first-order concept..)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Well, if we're doing set theory, then a topological space is not a structure at all.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok. Regardless it's hard to see why the question hasn't  been edited...

Comment: Ullrich I confused it with the lexigographic order!!! And then after submitting  the quetsion and as soon as Henning made the comment..I realize the triviality

Comment: @GeorgeChailos: A lot of unnecessary shouting could have been avoided here if you had made it clearer at that point that you had already solved the problem. You did write "thanks" and "I appreciate it", but many askers use that kind of wording in anticipation of future help, so it still left doubt. Even now, you ought to _accept egreg's answer_ by clicking on the outlined green checkmark to the left of the answer. This will mark your question as satisfactorily resolved in the system.

Answer (score 1):

If $(A,<_A)$ and $(B,<_B)$ are partially ordered sets (strict orders), their product is $(A\times B,<_{A\times B})$ where
$$
(a_1,b_1)<_{A\times B} (a_2,b_2)
\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad
a_1<_A a_2 \quad\text{and}\quad b_1<_B b_2
$$

Now, finding counterexamples to “if $(A,<_A)$ and $(B,<_B)$ are totally ordered then $(A\times B,<_C)$ is totally ordered” is quite easy.

Suppose $a_1<_A a_2$ in $A$ and $b_2<_B b_1$. Consider the two pairs $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ in $A\times B$. Can you find an instance?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Since he's not willing to say: What _is_ that definition? In particular what's the definition of a binary relation on the product of two structues with binary relations?

Comment: By the way, I was partially wrong in my first comment. This strict variant is still a categorical product, just in a different category, namely that of posets and _strictly_ order-preserving maps. I overlooked that the available morphisms are then different.

Comment: @egreg  About your counterexample:  If we added an ordering A < B, then would this allow us to define a total ordering on AxB?  I apologize that I'm not writing out this idea fully, but I believe you can get the idea.  If needed I could flesh out this idea in the form of a stackexchange question.

Comment: @Chris You can define different orders on the product set, that make it totally ordered. But they’re not the product order in the sense of the universal property of the product.

Comment: @egreg I was wondering if you could direct me towards such work on ways of making the product set totally ordered.  If you could give me some search terms that would be great.    I'd hate to do work that has already been done. Thanks.  ps.  Can you explain a universal property?

Comment: @Chris Lexicographic order…